# Calculate definite Integral

Tags: integration

I=$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=\sqrt\frac{\pi}{a}$

But if we change variable: $ax^2=t$

I=$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{2\sqrt{at}}dt=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\Gamma(\frac12)=\frac12\sqrt\frac{\pi}{a}$

Where's wrong?
True answer is $\sqrt\frac{\pi}{a}$

Comment: Your bounds are from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: But t lie within range 0 ti $\infty$, because of $t=x^2/a, a>0$

Comment: You are right in the sense that the range is from $0$ to $\infty$, but if you plug in $\pm \infty$ into $x$ you will get $\infty$ and $\infty$ not $0$ and $\infty$.

Comment: My suggestion to you is to break the integral into two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$I = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx = 2\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-ax^2}dx$$

Put $ax^2=t^2\;,$ Then $2axdx=-2tdt\Rightarrow axdx=tdt$

So $\displaystyle dx=\frac{t\sqrt{a}}{at}dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}dt$

So $$I = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-t^2}dt = \frac{2}{\sqrt{a}}\times \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

$\bf{Calculation\;  of \; \displaystyle \int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-x^2}dx}$

Let $\displaystyle J = \int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-x^2}dx$

Replace $x\rightarrow ax\;,$ Then $\displaystyle J = \int^{\infty}_{0}ae^{-a^2x^2}dx$

So $$J\times e^{-a^2}  = \int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-a^2(1+x^2)}adx$$

So $$J\times \int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-a^2}da  = \int^{\infty}_{0}\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-a^2(1+x^2)}adadx=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$$

So $$J\times J = \frac{\pi}{4}\Rightarrow J = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is an even function so you can write
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-ax^{2}} dx
= 2 \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-ax^{2}} dx$$ 
Your subsequent steps are correct.